# rPI access point devices can't see upnp devices, but can access by ip. Missing iptable or incorrect interface setup?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet, iptables

I posted yesterday, but forgot my login, sorry guys :(

I setup a basic wireless access point to access my ethernet network from my wifi devices not near it. I can access devices by ip just fine, but devices connected to the wifi network can't see upnp clients.

Is it not possible to have a 192.168.200.X device able to see a 192.168.100.X device? Or did something wrong happen in my iptables. I turned **on multicast** and forwarded all accepted traffic, but it still doesn't see anything.

-Laptop and devices connect to network directly, can see upnp.

-**Same devices connect to the access point setup, can't see upnp, but can access by ip.**

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3c:28:61
          inet addr:192.168.100.172  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d71d:f9d3:2b2a:6b35/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:253943 errors:0 dropped:479 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:71726392 (68.4 MiB)  TX bytes:3306886 (3.1 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:287385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:287385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:31559826 (30.0 MiB)  TX bytes:31559826 (30.0 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:60:05:fe:c4
          inet addr:192.168.200.1  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2eea:b3:db71:47d4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1832 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3509 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:307048 (299.8 KiB)  TX bytes:1480490 (1.4 MiB)
```

Iptables

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Apr 16 17:41:18 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [110:8692]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [94:11414]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr 16 17:41:18 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Apr 16 17:41:18 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8:1531]
:INPUT ACCEPT [8:1531]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7:752]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:296]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr 16 17:41:18 2016
```